# Запретить "пушить" в массив, если его длина превышает 8?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Как запретить "пушить" в массив, если его длина превышает 8?

Где `lengthMesseges` - получают длину из "геттера"

Где `sentMessege` - "пушит" в массив

```js
methods: {
    ...mapMutations(["createMessage"]),
    sentMessege() {
      this.createMessage({
        messege: this.messege
      });
      if (lengthMesseges==8) {
        !sentMessege
      }
    }
  },
  computed: mapGetters(["lengthMesseges"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, при условиях, что:

`lengthMessages` - длина массива `messages` в `vuex state`

проверяем длину в методе добавления `pushMessage`, как :

```
pushMessage() {
  if (this.lengthMessages < 8) {
    this.createMessage({
      text: `item ${this.lengthMessages + 1}`
    })
  }
}
```

Привожу пример:

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    messages: []
  },
  getters: {
    lengthMessages: state => state.messages.length,
  },
  mutations: {
    createMessage(state, data) {
      state.messages.push(data);
    }
  },
})
const {
  mapState,
  mapMutations,
  mapGetters
} = Vuex
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  name: 'vuexTest',
  store,
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState(['messages']),
    ...mapGetters(['lengthMessages'])
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations(['createMessage']),
    sentMessege() {
      if (this.lengthMessages < 8) {
        this.createMessage({
          text: `item ${this.lengthMessages + 1}`
        })
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.3.0/dist/vuex.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="sentMessege">push</button>
  <br>количество записей (vuex messages) = {{ lengthMessages }}
  <pre>{{ $store.state }}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо я сделал так в мутациях createMessage(state, newMessege) {
      if(state.messages.length<8){
        state.messages.push(newMessege)
      }
Но как вместо state.messages.length кидать геттер lengthMesseges в мутации?

Comment: согласно руководства `vuex` в мутациях допустимо два параметра - `state` и `payload`. Это завязано на том, что мутации синхронные транзакции и рекомендуется, чтобы они были быстрыми т.е. только меняли состояние хранилища, а не выполняли трудную логику. Но если вы хотите все-таки проверить какие-либо условия в мутации, то у вас есть полный доступ к `state` и геттер здесь излишнее действие

Comment: а почему вас не устраивает `if(state.messages.length<8){ state.messages.push(newMessege) }` ?

Comment: Просто интересно ли можно в мутации кинуть функцию с гетера

Comment: Я вас понял, думаю мой предыдущий комментарий развеял ваши сомнения)